# Which event fired off the callback function

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript

I have a FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE event for a popup that conflicts with the click event of a LinkButton that triggered the popup. In essence, I want the click event of my label to open/close the popup  like a switch each time it's clicked. The other way this popup can be closed is by a FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE.

The two conflict particularly when the FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE is clicked upon the popup triggering LinkButton.

What I am thinking is that I would stop propagation of the event if it is clicked upon on the LinkButton/ But how can I do this. Essentially, how in my callback function can I check what event actually fired this off (there are multiple event listeners for the element, so it is not failsafe )

Here is some code to chew upon:

```
element.addEventListener(FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE, callBackFunction, false, 0, true);  
element.addEventListener(AnotherEvent, callBackFunction, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: as a side note, I also would need to know on what element FlexMouseEvent clicks itself so that it only stops propagating

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Each event has a currentTarget property which is the object that fired off the event. You can use e.currentTarget to figure out which object the user clicked on.

```
private function mouseDownOutside(e:FlexEvent = null):void{
    if ( e.currentTarget == obj ) {
         //do something
    }
}
```

If you need it to be a bit more generic or the object is out of scope, you could also do a simple "is" check.

```
if ( e.currentTarget is DataType ) {
    //do something
}
```

This is also helpful for times when you are creating massive amounts of objects in a loop. They fall out of scope the second you leave the loop, so you can't really call them afterward. So, say you create a gallery with 50 thumbnails and you want to load a fullscreen version of the thumb the user clicks on. In your instantiation loop, you set the `name` property of your thumb to be the iteration in your loop (usually var i) and then you can use `(e.currentTarget as DisplayObject).name` to associate it with a larger image.

Comment: ummm...I have been inspecting both currentTarget and target events. I think currentTarget is the object upon which the event actions will take result upon. Essentially it is the element to which the addEventListener was added to.

Comment: I think he meant target; not currentTarget.  Keep in mind that many Flex components are created using encapsulation of other components.  I don't know if the target will always be the component you think it will be.

Comment: No, I meant currentTarget. Looking back at the question, I think I may have read it wrong. Regardless, currentTarget is the object that dispatches the event. So if you have two items with mouse_outside events, but only want to fire code when one of those events fires, you verify the currentTarget is the object before firing any code. If I am still reading it wrong and what you need to do is not fire this code when you click on another object, you would probably have to compare mouse and object positions, unfortunately. Sorry for not understanding.